Where better store transformers for dto
On my work i often discuss with my techlead about storaging serializers/deserializers.
He says, that all transformers must be arrow funcs (dto) => obj and must be placed in other file, user.transformer.ts, for example.
But i like to make it in another way: I make api-service, that only make rest request, deserialize and return observable of deserialized data. Serializator is a static function in this api-service.
For several months we cannot find a compromise or best variants to satisfy both of us.
What prefer you, or what the best practice?
I expected, that you can give me some argumented variants, wha I must use this way, or why I musn't use this way.
